# How do I bind a string to a DataContext while having multiple DataContexts?

Tags: wpf, binding, devexpress, datacontext

I am using a custom library and I have to bind a SQL connection string to the SqlGeometryDataAdapter. If I use the following approach, I am unable to declare more than one DataContext as the code won't compile unless I set the ConnectionString **as**

> ="{Binding}"/>

**and NOT**

> ="{Binding WKT}"/>

---

XAML:

```
<dxm:VectorLayer x:Name="WKT_Layer" DataLoaded="WKT_Layer_DataLoaded">
    <dxm:SqlGeometryDataAdapter x:Name="WKT_Adapter"
                                SqlText = "SELECT [WKT], [SID],[FILL],[STROKE] FROM [TLORIS] ORDER BY [SID]"
                                SpatialDataMember = "WKT"
                                ConnectionString="{Binding}"/>
</dxm:VectorLayer>
```

XAML.CS:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = WKT;
}

public string WKT { get; } = "Data Source=127.0.0.1; Initial Catalog=TESTDB; Connection Timeout=2; Persist Security Info=True; User=SA; Password=PASSWORD";
```

---

I am able to circumvent this problem by creating a class and declaring a string inside of it, but there must be an easier way to accomplish this?

---

XAML:

```
<dxm:VectorLayer x:Name="WKT_Layer" DataLoaded="WKT_Layer_DataLoaded">
    <dxm:SqlGeometryDataAdapter x:Name="WKT_Adapter"
                                SqlText = "SELECT [WKT], [SID],[FILL],[STROKE] FROM [TLORIS] ORDER BY [SID]"
                                SpatialDataMember = "WKT"
                                ConnectionString="{Binding WKT}"/>
</dxm:VectorLayer>
```

XAML.CS:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = SQLConnection.GetSQLConnection();
}

class SQLConnection
{
    public string WKT { get; set; }

    public static SQLConnection GetSQLConnection()
    {
        return new SQLConnection() { WKT = "Data Source=127.0.0.1; Initial Catalog=TESTDB; Connection Timeout=2; Persist Security Info=True; User=SA; Password=PASSWORD;" };
    }
}
```

Comment: `DataContext = WKT;` makes no sense. In order to bind to the WKT property of the MainWindow, set `DataContext = this;`.

Comment: @Clemens DataContext = WKT; works as long as I leave ConnectionString="{Binding}"/>, which makes it even more confusing as the Binding was never declared.

Comment: `"{Binding}"` binds directly to the current DataContext, which then contains the value of the WKT property.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer:**

DataContext = WKT; makes no sense. In order to bind to the WKT property of the MainWindow, set DataContext = this;. @Clemens

Comment: while this gives you the answer for now, the approach is totally wrong. You should keep View and ViewModel separate. Create a proper ViewModel class and set that class as your DataContext.

Comment: Would you say that the second approach in my initial question is suitable?

Comment: I don't see a second approach, but you should certainly read about MVVM